# Error "NU3034 This package is signed but not by a trusted signer"

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Today I found myself unable to restore NuGet packages on my machine. Doing so produces errors resembling:

> Myproject.csproj : error NU3034: Package 'SomePackage 1.2.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.

How can I fix package restore?

Answer (score 6):

Running `nuget trusted-signers list` showed I had one trusted signer by the name of "NuGet Test Developer".

This was present in `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` under the `<trustedSigners>` node.

Commenting out the entire `<trustedSigners>` node allowed restore to complete successfully.

It may also be possible to use `nuget trusted-signers Add -Name nuget.org` to explicitly trust packages from nuget.org, but in my case I don't believe I need the "NuGet Test Developer" signator.

It may also be possible to use `nuget config -set signatureValidationMode=accept` to disable signature validation altogether.

I found [this article](https://haacked.com/archive/2019/04/03/nuget-package-signing/) useful for learning more about NuGet package signing.

Comment: Thanks. Only disabling <trustedSigners> node allowed restore to complete successfully. With todays issue with Nuget and NET Core 5.

Comment: how did you do that? @LeszekP

Comment: @Maslow: find files with name nuget.config on C: drive. Edit them, if you find  <trustedSigners> xml node.

Comment: there's no c drive on linux

Comment: @Maslow try `find / -iname NuGet.config`

Answer (score 4):

If someone tried everything said by Drew Noakes, but still is getting error you can also try running command:

```
nuget trusted-signers sync -Name <name>
```

Which fixed this error for me.

[Here is link to documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-trusted-signers#nuget-trusted-signers-sync--name-name)