Asp .net core project build fails showing all nuget packages not signed by a trusted signer
Build failed of an asp.net core project showing the all nuget packages not signed by a trusted signer.

Tried to build the asp.net core project. Expected the build to succeed, but failed with all nuget packages marked as unsigned by a trusted signer.

does this case help to solve  the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334527

Thanks for your reply. It gives me the following error:

C:\Users\Rubaiyat\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.13.2\cli_x64>nuget trusted-signers Sync -Name NuGetTrust
WARNING: Failed to load C:\Users\Rubaiyat\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.13.2\cli_x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Unknown command: 'trusted-signers'
